# "Para distinguir los comentarios del código", anfibología y ambigüedad en frases

Tags: sintaxis, ambigüedad, desambiguación

Les traigo una duda que surgió a raíz de una pregunta que tuve que responder en un examen sobre programación hace algún tiempo. Era de opción múltiple, solo recuerdo la "pregunta" y la respuesta correcta, que es lo único que importa, como ya verán. Lo que debía responder:

> Una de las razones por las que debemos ser cuidadosos y consistentes con el formato de indentación es ...

Respuesta correcta que había que elegir (entre todas las que habían):

> para distinguir los comentarios del código.

Finalizada la prueba, le reclamo a mi profesor por esa pregunta argumentando que la respuesta está expresada ambiguamente. Le digo que en la jerga de la programación existen dos acepciones para *código*, a saber: el conjunto de lineas de código propiamente dicho (que tienen un significado para el compilador) y el conjunto de todas las lineas del archivo (es decir las anteriores incluyendo a los comentarios también). Por tanto, no se puede determinar si *del código* es una propiedad que afecta a *los comentarios* (A), o si en cambio ambas construcciones están al mismo nivel en la oración y entonces *del* debe entenderse como una conjunción que une dos miembros de igual jerarquía (B). Por lo que, en base a esto, las dos interpretaciones posibles serían:

> (A) para distinguir los comentarios entre sí (estando éstos dentro del código)

> (B) para distiguir lineas que están comentadas de las que no lo están

El profesor me dio la razón así también como mis compañeros, ninguno dudó en comprender que es correcto el planteo que hice.

Pero después, mientras estaba hablando sobre esto con un amigo, yo le digo que en esa frase no hay otra forma de resolver la ambigüedad más que reformulándola. Pero él me dice que eso no es cierto, si se agrega una coma de tal modo que la cláusula de la respuesta quede:

> para distinguir los comentarios, del código.

Entonces se resuelve la ambigüedad porque *del código* se transforma en una aposición y unívocamente se entenderá que dicha construcción refiere a una propiedad que afecta a *los comentarios*. Yo le dije que ese uso es incorrecto y que *del código* es un modificador indirecto, que de ninguna manera puede transformarse en una aposición, la frase así no tiene sentido y simplemente está mal escrita. Entonces comenzó una discusión picante en todo el curso en la que una mitad le dio la razón a mi amigo y la otra mitad a mí. ¿Quién está en lo cierto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Una de las razones por las que debemos ser cuidadosos y consistentes con el formato de indentación es para distinguir los comentarios del código.*

Como tu observas, la frase puede sugerir más de una interpretación. Así de forma ambigua, en el habla, se podría interpretar;

- que la indentación es para distinguir los comentarios del código (distinguir, los comentarios, del resto del código).
- que la indentación es para distinguir los comentarios del código (distinguir solo los comentarios que hay relativos o pertenecientes al código).

Normalmente para evitar esto, sería necesario reescribir y acomodar las palabras de manera que las ideas estén lo más claras posibles, ya que la oración por sí sola, sin ninguna explicación adicional, puede considerarse en el mejor de los casos, ambigua, en cuanto a significado, o incompleta en el peor, por el equivoco que representa.

- *Una de las razones por las que debemos ser cuidadosos y consistentes con el formato de indentación es para distinguir entre los comentarios y el código.*
- *Una de las razones por las que debemos ser cuidadosos y consistentes con el formato de indentación es para distinguir los comentarios del resto del código.*
- *Una de las razones por las que debemos ser cuidadosos y consistentes con el formato de indentación es para distinguir los comentarios y el código que hay entre ellos.*

*No he añadido comas, con el fin de respetar el texto original.*

Este tipo de frases ambivalentes, afecta desde hace tiempo a la ortografía, y no hay que confundir la figura de la "aposición", con los signos de puntuación que nos sirven para marcar e interpretar las oraciones con mayor comprensión y legibilidad. Por lo tanto, decir que la frase pueda resolverse transformando, "*del código*", en "*para distinguir los comentarios, del código*", en una aposición, con solo añadir una coma, es desconocer que significa una "aposición". Ejem. "Mariano, mi primo, consiguió trabajo de chofer". El río Ebro desemboca en el Mediterráneo.

Una aposición es una aclaración, una construcción con dos elementos gramaticales unidos, uno de los cuales especifica al otro, añadiendo contenido a través de la yuxtaposición de elementos, es decir, sin conectores. En el caso especifico de esta frase, con una sola coma detrás de "comentarios", no aclara ni explica nada, por lo que no se hubiera logrado el fin que pretendía.

Normalmente la aposición suele aparecer entre comas, pero no toda explicación que aparezca entre estos signos es necesariamente una aposición.

Las aposiciones pueden ser de dos tipos:

- **Aposición explicativa**. Como complemento del nombre, aporta información extra, y **siempre va entre comas**, dado que tiene un carácter parentético.

  Ejem. Nuria, la hija de Carmen, se ve buena chica. En este caso, “la hija de Carmen” es una aposición explicativa que aclara quién es Nuria, el núcleo del sujeto.
- **Aposición especificativa**. Es un complemento del nombre y aporta información específica adicional para diferenciar ese elemento o sujeto de los demás. **No se encuentra entre comas, sino que aparece unido al nombre que modifica**, con el cual forma un sintagma nominal. Muchas veces son nombres propios acompañados de determinados sustantivos comunes generales.

Ejem. La tía Carmen vendrá a visitarnos mañana. En este caso, "Carmen" es una aposición especificativa que diferencia a esta tía de las demás.

Por tanto;

*Una de las razones por las que debemos ser cuidadosos y consistentes con el formato de indentación es para distinguir los comentarios, del código.*

No es una aposición e incluso hace que la frase sea menos legible.

Para aproximarnos a la aposición y darle ese sentido de yuxtaposición a la oración, la sentencia que queremos resaltar o explicar, debería ir entre comas.

Aquí tenemos una frase ambigua;

Ejem. "Vendo una cuna para niños de madera".

- Vendo una cuna para niños de madera.
- Vendo una cuna de madera para niños.

Una forma de intentar arreglar la sentencia, dentro de lo que ya esta hecho, es utilizar signos de puntuación;

"Vendo una cuna, para niños, de madera".

En la frase que nos ocupa, en la que no hay ni una sola coma, podríamos matizar su significado a través de comas.

Ejem.

Una de las razones, por las que debemos ser cuidadosos y consistentes con el formato de indentación es para distinguir, los comentarios, del código.

En la respuesta al menos, "los comentarios", debería haber ido entre comas, con objeto de haber intentado diferenciar una cosa (los comentarios) de la otra (el código).

> Respuesta correcta que había que elegir (entre todas las que habían):
>
> "*para distinguir, los comentarios, del código*".